# C++ Process exited after 4.017 seconds with return value 3221225477

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am new to C++ and I am trying to write this simple code where I input and display employee data. 
I want to pass the user input to the **inputEmployee** function by address, save it in an array then display it. When I get to the part of typing the employee name I get the following message **"Process exited after 4.017 seconds with return value 3221225477"**.

Could someone please suggest a solution or explain what is wrong with my code.

I am not sure if what I'm doing is right.

```
struct Employee {
    char    name[30];
    char    surname[30];
    int     age;
    float   salary;
};

Employee* inputEmployee(struct Employee *emp, int n, int index) {
     Employee *employeeRecords = new Employee[n];
     employeeRecords[index] = *emp;
     return employeeRecords;
}

int displayEmployee(struct Employee *arr) {
    int arraySize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    printf("\nEmployee data:");
    for(int i=0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        printf("Name: %s", arr[i].name);
        printf("Surname: %d", arr[i].surname);
        printf("Age: %d", arr[i].age);
        printf("Salary: %f\n", arr[i].salary);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("\nEnter employee number :\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct Employee *eArr;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        struct Employee *emp = NULL;

        printf("\nEnter employee data :\n");
        printf("Name ?:"); scanf("%s", emp->name);
        printf("Surname ?:"); scanf("%s", emp->surname);
        printf("Age ?:"); scanf("%d", &emp->age);
        printf("Salary ?:"); scanf("%f", &emp->salary);
        eArr = inputEmployee(emp, n, i);
    }

    displayEmployee(eArr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do `struct Employee *emp = NULL;` followed by `scanf("%s", emp->name);`. What else would you expect to happen?

Comment: And if you're using C++, then why are you doing everything the C way?

Comment: I just added the = NULL to try what would happen, since the same error was given even without it.

Comment: Where do you clean up `Employee *employeeRecords = new Employee[n];`? A `std::vector` would make your life easier.

Comment: I am new to all this so I am not sure which is the right way to go. Thank you for the suggestion Thomas

Comment: Generally, if someone doesn't understand why a C++ program doesn't work, making random changes to the program, like setting various variables to `NULL`, is unlikely to result in anything productive. You need to understand the reason for the crash, then fix it. The reason for the crash is not correcty instantiating objects, and dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Replacing the dereference of an uninitialized pointer with a dereference of a NULL pointer is not going to fix the problem.

Comment: Best advice I can give is *"you don't code by trying things to see what would happen"* -- that's called **guessing**. Syntax and use in C/C++ is exact. Every character in a line has a purpose and correct use. If you find yourself tempted to *guess*, then that little voice should be telling you *"don't do it -- go back to the books or man page and figure it out..."*. No exceptions.

Comment: Every time you input a new employee you create a new array and store the new employee in it but you lose all the other information

Comment: Just noticed that. Thanks Thomas

Comment: `int arraySize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);` does NOT give you the number of elements in the array, instead it provides `sizeof(arr) / sizeof (a_pointer)` -- not what you want. You must pass the number of elements as a second parameter. `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` -- *Only Works Within The Scope In Which* `arr` *was declared as an array* When passed as a parameter (actually on access), an array is converted to a pointer to the fist element - subject to a few exceptions not relevant here..

Comment: When you get a big/weird number like 3221225477, convert it to hex (C0000005) and see if it's more familiar (access violation - the program tried to use memory that it did not own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go a step back and read something about memory management, arrays, pointers and references in C++. This is a hard part, you have to learn, when you want to program C++. You should definitely read some more articles.

Learning-by-doing is only half the the way to go here. You need to understand what happens in the background. Your program can do 'something', even if it seems okay, it could fail badly later on. But keep your head up on go on.

---

`Employee *emp = NULL;` creates a pointer to 'nowhere' in your memory. The least thing you have to do, is `Employee *emp = new Employee();`. This will allocate memory you can use for your data. Please keep in mind, that you have to use the `delete` operator for each allocated memory.

I tried to fix your code. I allocated memory for the whole array.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Employee
{
  char name[30];
  char surname[30];
  int age;
  float salary;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int displayEmployee(Employee *arr, int count)
{
  printf("\nEmployee data:");
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    printf("Name: %s ", arr[i].name);
    printf("Surname: %s ", arr[i].surname);
    printf("Age: %d ", arr[i].age);
    printf("Salary: %f\n", arr[i].salary);
  }
  return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  printf("\nEnter employee number: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  Employee *eArr = new Employee[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    Employee &emp = eArr[i];

    printf("\nEnter employee data :\n");
    printf("Name ?: ");
    scanf("%s", emp.name);
    printf("Surname ?: ");
    scanf("%s", emp.surname);
    printf("Age ?: ");
    scanf("%d", &(emp.age));
    printf("Salary ?: ");
    scanf("%f", &(emp.salary));
    // eArr = inputEmployee(emp, n, i);
  }
  displayEmployee(eArr, n);

  delete[] eArr;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you

Comment: Note: you must ***validate*** every user-input by ***checking the return*** and handle `EOF`, and *matching* failures, and you must clear `stdin` of any extraneous or erroneous character prior to the next input -- otherwise you temp *Undefined Behavior* or risk an infinite loop.

Comment: David is correct. In order to have working code, you have to do validate the inputs. This is always important in C++. In the best case your program crashes. In the worst case it does something strange and unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a fine answer, but there are several additional points you must cover in order to have any confidence in your input routine. Primarily, you must ***validate every user input*** and you must empty `stdin` of any additional characters before the next input. Ask your self what would happen if you entered `"Ninety One"` for `Age`? Clearing `stdin` can be done with a simple loop continuing with your C-stye input or using `std::cin.ignore()` if using iostream.

For example, when you loop to collect the employee data, you must force the user to enter valid input ***for each variable*** before moving on the store the next, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* loop for input of n empoloyees */
        struct Employee emp;

        puts ("\nEnter employee data :");
        for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
            fputs ("\n  Name ?: ", stdout);     /* prompt (fputs for \n control) */
            int rtn = scanf("%s", emp.name);    /* save return from scanf */
            if (rtn == EOF) {                   /* check for manual EOF */
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }   /* remove any extraneous characters from stdin */
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)                       /* if good input break loop */
                break;
        }
```

You must add an additional check when handling numeric-input to cover the *matching-failure* case, e.g.

```
        for (;;) {  /* ditto for Age, but note the additional validation required */
            fputs ("  Age ?: ", stdout);
            int rtn = scanf ("%d", &emp.age);
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        }
```

If you have a requirement that the number enter be within a particular rage, you can add an additional check such as `if (emp.age < 16 || emp.age > 80)` handle the error for an invalid age.

For output, you do not need multiple `printf`(or `std::cout`) calls -- one will do, e.g.

```
/* No return, you must pass number of elements as second parameter */
void displayEmployee (struct Employee *arr, int n)
{
    puts ("\nEmployee data:");      /* no conversion, just use puts */

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)       /* only 1 printf needed */
        printf ("\n  Name: %s\n  Surname: %s\n  Age: %d\n  Salary: %.2f\n",
                arr[i].name, arr[i].surname, arr[i].age, arr[i].salary);
}
```

Also note there is no reason to return a value from `displayEmployee`, it is simply an output function and there is nothing to return to indicate success or failure of an operation within the function.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define MAXN 30

struct Employee {
    char    name[MAXN];
    char    surname[MAXN];
    int     age;
    float   salary;
};

/* No return, you must pass number of elements as second parameter */
void displayEmployee (struct Employee *arr, int n)
{
    puts ("\nEmployee data:");      /* no conversion, just use puts */

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)       /* only 1 printf needed */
        printf ("\n  Name: %s\n  Surname: %s\n  Age: %d\n  Salary: %.2f\n",
                arr[i].name, arr[i].surname, arr[i].age, arr[i].salary);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    fputs ("\nEnter employee number : ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {                    /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    struct Employee *eArr = new struct Employee[n]; /* allocate */

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* loop for input of n empoloyees */
        struct Employee emp;

        puts ("\nEnter employee data :");
        for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
            fputs ("\n  Name ?: ", stdout);     /* prompt (fputs for \n control) */
            int rtn = scanf("%s", emp.name);    /* save return from scanf */
            if (rtn == EOF) {                   /* check for manual EOF */
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }   /* remove any extraneous characters from stdin */
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)                       /* if good input break loop */
                break;
        }
        for (;;) {  /* ditto for Surname */
            fputs ("  Surname ?: ", stdout);
            int rtn = scanf("%s", emp.surname);
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
        }
        for (;;) {  /* ditto for Age, but note the additional validation required */
            fputs ("  Age ?: ", stdout);
            int rtn = scanf ("%d", &emp.age);
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        }
        for (;;) {  /* ditto for Salary with same note */
            fputs ("  Salary ?: ", stdout);
            int rtn = scanf ("%f", &emp.salary);
            if (rtn == EOF) {
                puts ("(user canceled input)");
                return 0;
            }
            for (char c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
            if (rtn == 1)
                break;
            fputs ("error: invalid floating-point input.\n", stderr);
        }
        eArr[i] = emp;  /* simply assign struct to element */
    }

    displayEmployee(eArr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/empstruct

Enter employee number : 3

Enter employee data :

  Name ?: Mickey
  Surname ?: Mouse
  Age ?: 91
  Salary ?: 88.82

Enter employee data :

  Name ?: Minnie
  Surname ?: Mouse
  Age ?: 88
  Salary ?: 93.25

Enter employee data :

  Name ?: Goofy
  Surname ?: Dog
  Age ?: 85
  Salary ?: Bone and Treats
error: invalid floating-point input.
  Salary ?: .25

Employee data:

  Name: Mickey
  Surname: Mouse
  Age: 91
  Salary: 88.82

  Name: Minnie
  Surname: Mouse
  Age: 88
  Salary: 93.25

  Name: Goofy
  Surname: Dog
  Age: 85
  Salary: 0.25
```

Try entering an invalid input for either `Age` or `Salary` with your current code and see what happens (have your fingers hovering over <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> when you do... or see which input appears to be skipped)

Also, you should pick either C or C++. What you have is a C program that uses `new` instead of `malloc` for allocation. If you replace your allocation with `new` with `struct Employee *eArr = malloc (n * sizeof *eArr);` then you have a pure C program. There is nothing invalid about mixing the languages, but it is not looked upon well.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: You are welcome. Learning either C or C++ is more of a journey than something you just do. There is so much to either language, it is far more than you can digest in a year or two. Don't make it a race, just enjoy the journey and strive for understanding each aspect of the language in detail, not just at a cursory level. You learn to program the same way you eat a whale -- one byte at a time....